# Is there a vmware appliance for software development?

Tags: deployment, virtual-appliances

I use Assembla.com and it does everything I need, SVN, bug tracking, ticketing...
the only thing I don't like is that the server is not mine, I'm putting all my company property on a server in the coulds. I was wondering if there is an virtual machine to download and put on my server to serve all Assembla does?

Answer (score 2):

You may want to have a look around the [turnkey linux](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/) website. When I was looking for an easy way to evaluate an integrated bug tracking/SCM server I found the [TRAC](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/trac) and [Redmine](http://www.turnkeylinux.org/redmine) appliances interesting, if not quite what we needed at the time. Your mileage may vary however.

Oh, and if you're not absolutely wedded to SVN, you may want to check out [Mercurial](http://mercurial.selenic.com/) for your SCM, you'll never want to go back to SVN after trying it. Distributed revision control is a breath of fresh air after years of 'tranditional' source control and if you use [TortoiseSVN](http://tortoisesvn.tigris.org/), then [TortoiseHg](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.org/) will be a breeze.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, i can't reach assembla.com right now - seems to be down =)

I don't know of a VM that contains all these tools, but i'm sure it'll be easy to set one up really fast.

Another question: Do you think it's such a good idea? I would pick an old pentium 3 from ebay and set it up as dev-server (but remember to make backups, and backups and BACKUPS!).

Otherwise you'd have a vm running all the time without actually using it all the time. And even a P3 (or whatever you like) with a fast disk or raid controller may be faster than your VM.

Alternative: rent a virtual Server (Here in Europe: 3 GHz, 1024MB RAM, 30GB disk - 8€/Month).

Comment: Main point about assembla is all those tools are connected. there is a lot of setting up I can save if there is a vm image ready. and I already have a VMware server machine and all I have to do is to add this one.

8€/Month sounds great, which company is this?

Comment: netcup - a company from karlsruhe/germany. But there are a lot of other comanies with almost equal prices an maybe virtualization technologies better suited for your needs.

Hav you searched the VMWare Appliance Marketplace? http://www.vmware.com/appliances/

Comment: Bleh to setting up a cheap old PC as a dev server. Horrible idea. These things are the bane of IT supports life when you're 5 years down the line and you find what has become a 'critical production' server crammed under someone's desk. If you already run a virtual environment within your organisation, VMs are absolutely the way to go in this kind of scenario.

Comment: Ali didn't say in what kind of environment he will be using this server. And do you think it's better to run a VM of a dev server instead of a real server?

He didn't mention the existing VM host in the first place either. Compared to a service with unexplained downtimes an old machine seems a very good idea to me. 
A modern and stable (virtual-)machine is the best way to go if you're setting up a dev server in a company. But if you don't have the resources or need the server for yourself a small machine will/has to be enough. And i'm not talking about cheap, but reliable old hardware =)

Comment: Points taken. I wouldn't agree in any professional scenario, but if he's doing home dev with little budget, an old server would be a viable option.